# Android MapView - recourse for canceled animateTo

Tags: android, android-mapview, runnable

I have a `MapView` and I have a callback where I want to animate to a point on the map, and run some code.

```
mapController.animateTo(geoPoint, new Runnable() 
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        // run some code
    }
});
```

It says in [the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapController#animateTo%28com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint,%20java.lang.Runnable%29): "If and when the animation reaches its natural conclusion, this callback will be run on the UI thread. The callback will not be run if the animation is aborted."

It appears that there is a case I have to handle where the animation is aborted.  I'd like to run some different code if that happens.

Is there a good way to detect if the animation is aborted?

Comment: I am guessing that perhaps that an animation will be "aborted" when it is no longer relevant (e.g., the `MapActivity` is destroyed, via the user pressing BACK), but that is just a guess. I am not aware that you are informed about failed animations.

Comment: It seems the animation gets aborted by the user touching the screen during a pan or something else my code seems to be doing... I am having a hard time narrowing it down though.  Thanks for the help.